Understanding Y DNA and the FTDNA Haplotree better
I talked with FTDNA Corporate last week Friday before the week of Christmas. They agreed with me which the DNA Geek seems to agree there change in course of action is because of the 2021 Keddie Murder Investigation is involved. What I am trying to understand is if the FTDNA Phylogenetic Expert can confirm what my Group Project Admin has found if some of the Variants are split off of E-CTS9083,the Variants on E-L539 that are above the section that comprises E-V68 are split off from E-V68, most of the Variants are split off from E-CTS5856,a different SNP other than E-BY4877 is used to connect the split in E-CTS5856 to E-BY3880, a different branch from E-CTS6377 is used to connect E-SK888 and E-S12376 to E-CTS2001,and the other 3 men are given a new designation with a new branch off of E-CTS9320 with me and my Big Y Match having our branch connect off of the new branch of E-CTS9320 that the other 3 men with there new designation split off of would that be a significant difference to the our Haplogroup and the FTDNA Haplotree?
